# cocos2d sprite animation "SIGABRT"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

i have followed many videos on how tho animate sprites in cocos2d. But i seem to always com across this when the code is run.

CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode SpriteSheetWithFile:@"animbear.png"];

it says (Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGBRT")

im not sure what do do I've tried everything i can please help?

heres the code within the init method
heres the part of the code!

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

// HelloWorldLayer implementation

@implementation HelloWorldLayer
// At the top, under @implementation

@synthesize bear = _bear;

@synthesize moveAction = _moveAction;

@synthesize walkAction = _walkAction;

-(id) init {
    if((self = [super init])) {

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
         @"bear.plist"];      


        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode 
            batchNodeWithFile:@"bear.jpg"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];  

        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject: *****THIS IS WERE (PROGRAM RECEIVED SIGNAL:"SIGABRT***
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bear%d.png", i]]];
        }
            CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation 
            animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];       

            CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
            self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bear.jpg"];        
            _bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
            self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                               [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
            [_bear runAction:_walkAction];
            [spriteSheet addChild:_bear];        

        } 

    return self;
}
```

Comment: When this crashes, please press CMD + Shift + R, and copy/paste the contents of the console window into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added animbear.png to your project?

Comment: What's sad is I know what tutorial he is talking about because of animbear.png.

Comment: The answer to that is to get out more :)

Comment: Out? Out where? I don't like the sound of this "out" you speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you SAVE the sheet before publishing the PNG and PLIST file using Zwoptex